# How can I cancel all pending $timeouts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have some code that uses an AngularJS $timeout to call another function several times at specific intervals, using a loop. I'm trying to create a cancel function that will stop all the $timeouts from being processed. I realize I could probably do this with another loop, going through each $timeout, but sometimes the page will need to create thousands of $timeouts and so I was really hoping there would be some kind of way to stop all the currently pending $timeouts. The documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout seems to only really talk about using cancel() to stop a specific promise.

**Is it possible to cancel all currently pending $timeouts at once in AngularJS and if so, how?**

Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```
for(var i=1; i<=$scope.catalog.pages; i++) {
    $scope.catalog.timeouts['fetch'+i] = $timeout(function() {
        count++;
        if (!$scope.catalog.isCancelled) {
            $scope.results($scope.catalog.dataFile, {currentPage: count});
        } else {
            //cancel all the remaining timeouts somehow
        }
    }, 10*i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular timeouts works with promises, you could call the cancel method of that. [$timeout.cancel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#cancel)

```
$scope.catalog.timeouts.forEach(function(promises) {
    promises.cancel && promises.cancel();
});
```

Comment: That code gave me an error (forEach not a function). I tweaked it slightly, using the same general principle (iterating through each of the promises in a loop), and that does work.