# Controller life-cycle in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I defined m my application states using ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'nav@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/navbar.html',
        controller: 'NavbarController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      },
      'main@': {
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('child1', {
    url: '/child1',
    parent: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/child1.html',
    controller: function($timeout) {
      $timeout(function() {
        alert('from child_1');
      }, 15000)
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .state('child2', {
    url: '/child2',
    parent: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/child2.html',
    controller: 'ctrl_2',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
```

When I go from `/child1` to `/child2` quickly (before 15000 miliseconds), still I see the alert that was defined in `child1` controller, is this a normal behavior?

Comment: what do you mean by quickly?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I mean before 5 seconds, that is 2th argument of `$timeout` function in `child1` controller.

Comment: Timeout will surely work. Though angular service is there it is an window event. you need to clear the timeout in scope destroy event

Comment: may be this will work:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314833/how-can-i-cancel-all-pending-timeouts

Comment: I just used `$timeout` to show preserving the controller instance. It's the same for events, etc.

Comment: You must cancel all defined behavior manually: timeouts/watches/events and etc.. `scope.$on('$destroy', ...)` is designed for this.

Answer (score 2):

> is this a normal behavior?

Yes, this is normal behavior. Function references created and given to another function (such as the `$timeout` service) will last as long as the other function keeps that reference. In the case of the `$timeout` service, it will keep that reference for the duration of the timeout (in this case 15 seconds).

In addition if the child function uses local variables of the parent function, those local variables will be retained for the life of the child function. That process is known as "creating a closure".

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

The `$timeout` service needs to be told to cancel the timeout and remove the reference or it will persist beyond the life of the controller.

```
controller: function($timeout, $scope) {
  var promise = $timeout(function() {
    alert('from child_1');
  }, 15000);
  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    promise.cancel();
  });
},
```

In the above example, the `$timeout` service attaches a function called `cancel` to the promise that it returns. Client code can invoke that function to tell the `$timeout` service  to abort the timeout and release the reference to the function.

When the `ui-router` switches from `child1` state to another state, it destroys the scope of the controller. The controller should listen for the `$destroy` event and cancel the timeout.